# Run Oracle VM VirtualBox on Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, virtualbox

When I try to run `Oracle VM VirtualBox`, it says that I need to add a kernel module and recompile the Linux kernel for it to work.

The error I get is:

> WARNING: The vboxdrv kernel module is not loaded. Either there is no module
>   available for the current kernel or it failed to
>   load. Please recompile the kernel module and install it by
>
> sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup

I downloaded Oracle VM VirtualBox from their download site and selected the deb package for Ubuntu 13.04 AMD64

How would I do that?

Comment: Please share the method you are trying to use to install the package, and the precise error log.

Comment: @Ernir I edited the question to include the error and how I installed the package

Comment: Um...what's the output of `sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup`? I think you'll need to install some headers. What's the output of `uname -r`?

Comment: @Alaa When I run `sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup` it complains that it cannot find the kernel source

Comment: Please include the command's output in the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you have linux kernel headers and build essentials installed:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-headers-generic linux-headers-$(uname -r) build-essential dkms
```

Then run:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup
```

watch for errors.

Answer (score 3):

You need the dkms package to install VirtualBox, and the linux-kernel-headers package for your kernel. If those are present, Oracle VM Virtual Box should be able to be installed without issue.

Try:

```
$sudo dpkg -i virtualbox-4.2_4.2.16-86992~Ubuntu~precise_amd64.deb
```

That should tell you what is recommended/required to complete the install on your machine.

Hope that helps. Have a nice day!

Comment: While Wild Man answer is the one that will solve your problem, I also upvoted this as it can prevent it in the future, when you update your kernel.